# How to pass variable from VaadinServlet to UI?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, vaadin, guice

I'm new to Vaadin. I want to use it to build admin backend. As I am familiar DI (Guice), I would like to inject dependencies into servlet. However, I don't know how to pass from servlet to UI layer. Below is my sample codes:

```
@Singleton
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = classOf[LoginUI])
class TestServlet @Inject()(userDAO: UserDAO) extends VaadinServlet with LazyLogging {
  //How to userDAO to LoginUI?
  override def servletInitialized(): Unit = {
  }
}

@Theme("valo")
class LoginUI extends UI with LazyLogging {

  override def init(request: VaadinRequest) = {
    logger.debug("Init Login UI")
    val content: VerticalLayout = new VerticalLayout
    setContent(content)

    val label: Label = new Label("Hello, world!")
    content addComponent label

    content addComponent new Button("Click Me!",
      new ClickListener {
        override def buttonClick(event: ClickEvent) =
          Notification.show("The time is ")
      })
  }
}
```

I see that although it is UI, it acts like controller layer, so I think it does not anti-pattern when doing that. I find it even more difficult to inject things into UI. However, if I can inject directly into UI, it would be better.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Normally you would create a login-form and display it in a modal window, in your LoginUI class. You can inject into UI, but you must use the @CDIUI annotation, and if you absolutely have to overload the servlet, you must inherit from VaadinCDIServlet.

Comment: @jonmartinsolaas he uses guice, not cdi

Comment: @Jan ah, that's something else. Still - in order to have Vaadin work with DI, be it CDI or Spring, overriding the stock VaadinServlet causes trouble. Could that be the problem here as well? Edit: No, seems it should work, ref http://costachetheodor.blogspot.no/2014/05/vaadin-7-and-guice-30.html.

Comment: @jonmartinsolaas I have had a quick look at the blog. I think I may miss a point. According the source code of the blog, I still don't see how to inject into UI. https://github.com/theodorcostache/vaadin-guice/blob/master/src/main/java/de/costache/demo/MyVaadinUI.java It seem that the blog guides to inject into servlet which is not a problem to me. What I want is be able to inject userDAO in LoginUI class.

Comment: Injecting into UI would be the normal use case, at least with CDI or Spring. It seems Guice is not that well supported, or at least it's more complicated to set up. I found this framework: http://code.google.com/p/guice-vaadin-mvp and this: https://github.com/davidsowerby/krail (there is also a blog here: http://rndjava.blogspot.no/2013/01/vaadin-guice-and-shiro-done.html)